# "ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:" while trying to install p5 with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pip

```
C:\Users\Oskar>pip install p5
Collecting p5
 Using cached p5-0.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (100 kB)
Collecting triangle
 Using cached triangle-20200424-cp38-cp38-win32.whl (1.4 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\oskar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from p5) (1.19.1)
Collecting vispy
 Using cached vispy-0.6.4.tar.gz (13.3 MB)
 Installing build dependencies ... error
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
  command: 'c:\users\oskar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\oskar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\Oskar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-mku2s554\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- wheel 'setuptools>=30.3.0' setuptools_scm setuptools_scm_git_archive 'Cython>=0.29.2' 'numpy; python_version=='"'"'2.7'"'"'' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.5'"'"'' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version>='"'"'3.7'"'"''
      cwd: None
 Complete output (298 lines):
 Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "2.7"' don't match your environment
 Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.5"' don't match your environment
 Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6"' don't match your environment
```

I have been trying to install p5 with pip but I am getting this error. I have tried reinstalling python (3.8.5) and have done pip install -U setuptools. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with having several versions of python.

If you're using this module in python version, say 3.8 , then run:

```
python3.8 -m pip install p5 --user
```

For version 3.7 you'd do:

```
python3.7 -m pip install p5 --user
```

Also consider using virtual environments

**[EDIT]**
I did some further research and noticed you might have some unmet dependencies.
Do you have ***glfw*** installed and added to path? If not follow [here](https://p5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#prerequisites-glfw)

**[EDIT 2]**
Looks like the issue is yet to be resolved, I hope you find [this](https://github.com/p5py/p5/issues/144) useful

**[EDIT 3]**
Added `--user` flag

Comment: I tried "pip3 install p5" and "pip3.8 install p5" because "python3.8 -m pip install p5" wasnt recognized  but they both threw the same error as before

Comment: Try updating pip and cython like so: `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip cython`

Comment: When using "python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip cython" it outputs nothing but I did "pip install --upgrade pip cython" but it unfortunatly didnt help

Comment: What do you mean by 'it outputs nothing' , was there no response from the shell ?